# How to pass variables with special characters into a bash script when called from terminal

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

Hello all I have a program  running on a linux OS that allows me to call a bash script upon a trigger (such as a file transfer). I will run something like:

```
/usr/bin/env bash -c "updatelog.sh '${filesize}' '${filename}'"
```

and the scripts job is to update the log file with the file name and file size. But if I pass in a file name with a single quote in its file name then it will break the script and give an error saying `` "Unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''" ``

I realize that a file name with a single quote is making the calling command an invalid one since the single quote is messing with the command itself. However I don't want to sanitize the variables if I can help it cause I would like my log to have the exact file name being displayed to easier cross reference it later. Is this possible or is sanitizing the only option here?

Thanks very much for your time and assistance.

Comment: `/path/updatelog.sh "${filesize}" "${filename}"`

Comment: Exactly that. If there's a separate technical problem that's forcing you to add the `bash -c` instead of invoking your script directly, let's start by fixing that first.

Comment: By the way -- putting `.sh` extensions on your scripts is an antipattern: executable scripts define commands, and command names don't conventionally have extensions on UNIX (you run `ls`, not `ls.elf`; and `pip`, not `pip.py`). The essay [Commandname Extensions Considered Harmful](https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/) has been the canonical link on this topic from the #bash IRC channel's factoid bot for a long time.

Comment: ...if you have trouble applying the answer, please build a [mre] that lets that issue be reproduced end-to-end in an online sandbox; there are some ways one could conceivably break this code depending on how your trigger is invoked, but those are problems with the program having the "trigger" functionality, so if the answer I provided doesn't work, that program itself may need to be fixed. (More worryingly, if the answer I provided doesn't work, there's a good chance that program is prone to security bugs; the easiest ways to break it are making mistakes that also allow shell injection vulns).

Comment: Charles thanks so much! This helped immensely and taught me more about proper execution about bash. Thanks for including the educational material :) I would like to ask one more thing though. Apparently in the Linux file system you can have files with a double quote in its name. This will still break the execution I believe, I will take your advice and build a reproducible version online to view. I know this is a rare corner case but just wanted to cover my ground on possible corner cases.

Comment: Syntactic and literal quotes don't substitute for each other. If the program implementing the trigger is doing it right -- putting the literal name in an environment variable quotes and all -- those quotes will be understood by the shell to be data and not syntax. If they're substituting the quotes into the string when running the trigger... Well, that's why I said doing it wrong could have consequences for security.

Comment: By the way, the above (conflation of data and syntax) is also the reason for the common misconception underlying [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sanitization is *absolutely* not needed.

The simplest solution, assuming your script is properly executable (has `+x` permissions and a valid shebang line), is:

```
./updatelog.sh "$filesize" "$filename"
```

---

If for some reason you *must* use the `bash -c`, use single quotes instead of double quotes surrounding your code, and keep your data out-of-band from that code:

```
bash -c 'updatelog.sh "$@"' 'updatelog' "$filesize" "$filename"
```

Note that only `updatelog.sh "$@"` is inside the `-c` argument and parsed as code, and that this string is *in single quotes*, passed through without any changes whatsoever.

Following it are your arguments `$0`, `$1` and `$2`; `$0` is used when printing error messages, while `$1` and `$2` go into the list of arguments -- aka `$@` -- passed through to `updatelog.sh`.

Comment: This worked for me, thank you for taking the time to answer my questions under the main question and helping a fellow person out :) I hope you have an awesome day!